# Rename subfolders

Tags: linux, bash, find, cut

I try to fix my music folder, what itunes messed up.

So what I need is script to move files from:

music\Artist\Album name\Artist - title.mp3

to move files to

newmusic\Album name\Artist - title.mp3.

I tried the line below, but didin't work.

`find music  -type f  -exec bash -c 'ext="${0##*.}"; base="$(basename "$0" ."${ext}")"; dirs="$(dirname "$0" | cut -d '/' -f 2,3)"; new="newmusic/${dirs}/${base}.${ext}"; cp "$0" "${new}"' {} \;`

Does the "cut -d '/' -f 2,3" should be in new="newmusic/${{dirs} cut -d '/' -f 2,3}/
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance..

Comment: This sounds more like something for [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something here, or can `mv` not achieve what you want? Based on your question, this should work:

```
mv music/*/* newmusic/
```

Comment: "-bash: /bin/mv: Argument list too long."
And if just using mv command, it don't drop the 2 subfolder (Artist) off?

Answer (score 1):

```
for artist in music/*; do
  if [[ -d "$artist" ]]; then
    for album in $artist/*; do
      mv "$album/*" "newmusic/${album##*/}/"
    done
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Tricks, just avoid '-exec bash -c' you'll end up with unreadeable over-quoted-protected code.

Instead play with :

```
find -name .mp3 | while read file
do
    # Play with "$file"
    # Don't play with $file without doubles quotes, keep spaces in mind
    # Don't play with '$file', it'a common error ^^
done
```

Answer (score 0):

1.`cd` to your working directory

2.`find music/Artist -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec mv {} newmusic/ \;` should do the trick.

If you don't want to `mv` then you can replace mv with `cp -r`.

Comment: Artist is changing attribute, theres many artist, so can't type all them. Theres also space between some of folder names, like music/Artist\ /x/. We need for before that command, but somehow it brake the lines when theres space in folder name. Even when using ls -1, like this: for f in $( ls -1 music ); do find music/$f -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec echo {} newmusic/ \; done

Comment: find * -type d -mindepth 1 -exec cp -r {} ../newmusic/ \; worked, thanks for showing right path :)